# Template with packaged_task not compile

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction

I am playing with an example 4.14 from the book Antony Williams - C + + Concurrency in Action in which emulated std::async using std::packaged_task and std::thread.

Why this code does not compile when I uncomment lines and how to rewrite template to make it work?

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

void func_string(const std::string &x) {}

void func_int(int x) {}

template <typename F, typename A>
std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type> spawn_task(F &&f, A &&a) {
  typedef typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type result_type;
  std::packaged_task<result_type(A&&)> task(std::move(f));
  std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
  std::thread t(std::move(task), std::move(a));
  t.detach();
  return res;
}


int main () {
  std::string str = "abc";

  // auto res1 = spawn_task(func_string, str);
  // res1.get();
  auto res2 = spawn_task(func_int, 10);
  res2.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
nnovzver@archer /tmp $ clang++ -std=c++11 -lpthread temp.cpp && ./a.out
In file included from temp.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/future:38:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:56: error: no type
      named 'type' in 'std::result_of<std::packaged_task<void (std::basic_string<char> &)> (std::basic_string<char>)>'
      typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/thread:135:41: note: in instantiation
      of template class 'std::_Bind_simple<std::packaged_task<void (std::basic_string<char> &)>
      (std::basic_string<char>)>' requested here
        _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
                                        ^
temp.cpp:15:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<std::packaged_task<void
      (std::basic_string<char> &)>, std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
  std::thread t(std::move(task), std::move(a));
              ^
temp.cpp:24:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'spawn_task<void (&)(const
      std::basic_string<char> &), std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
  auto res1 = spawn_task(func_string, str);
              ^
In file included from temp.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/future:38:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1726:50: error: no type
      named 'type' in 'std::result_of<std::packaged_task<void (std::basic_string<char> &)> (std::basic_string<char>)>'
        typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Could you provide the compilation errors ?

Comment: The compilation works with a change to the function signature like this : `void func_string(std::string &&x)` and use `std::move(str)`. I am still unsure on how to handle properly perfect forwarding in the general case…

Comment: @galop1n It's a trick, because this works perfect `auto res = async(launch::async, func_string, str);` and I am trying to emulate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) of async, the feature you want to emulate, it decays all the future template arguments. And it is effective as it works far better like this, as show [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc803ebfcd8a48ca) :

```
template <typename T_>
using decay_t = typename std::decay<T_>::type;
template< class T >
using result_of_t = typename std::result_of<T>::type;

template <typename F, typename A>
std::future<result_of_t<decay_t<F>(decay_t<A>)>> spawn_task(F &&f, A &&a) {
    using result_t = result_of_t<decay_t<F>(decay_t<A>)>;
    std::packaged_task< result_t(decay_t<A>)> task(std::forward<F>(f));
    auto res = task.get_future();
    std::thread t(std::move(task), std::forward<A>(a));
    t.detach();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I actually made ​​a change in one line and it worked `std::packaged_task<result_type(decay_t<A>)> task(std::move(f));`. Without `std::forward` the book example is quite useless too.

Comment: @nnovzver `std::move` is bad, because if you pass in a non-rvalue element, you will `move` from it.  This is extremely rude.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `std::packaged_task` wraps any *Callable* target function. And one of the requirements of Callable is that it has a suitable return value. `void` is not a suitable return value. I changed your functions to return `int` for test purposes:

```
int func_string(const std::string &x) 
{
    return 1;
}

int func_int(int x) 
{
    return 2;
}
```

Secondly it looks to me like you've got a mismatch between your actual function signatures and what you are specifying in the `std::result_of<>` templates. Specifically your function signatures are:

```
int func_string(const std::string &x);
int func_int(int x);
```

but you are passing:

```
std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type result_type
```

changing that to:

```
std::result_of<F(A)>::type result_type
```

And everything compiles.

Here is the full source code (minus the headers):

```
int func_string(const std::string &x) 
{
    return 1;
}

int func_int(int x) 
{
    return 2;
}

template <typename F, typename A>
std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A)>::type> spawn_task(F &&f, A &&a) 
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<F(A)>::type result_type;
    std::packaged_task<result_type(A)> task(std::move(f));
    std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
    std::thread t(std::move(task), std::move(a));
    t.detach();
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abc";

     auto res1 = spawn_task(func_string, str);
     res1.get();
    auto res2 = spawn_task(func_int, 10);
    res2.get();
}
```

Comment: @galop1n Interesting - this compiles and runs correctly on VS2013.

Comment: Never trust a VS compiler…

Comment: Why is `void` not a suitable return type?  Second, `A&&` is the type of the argument passed to `spawn_task` (and need not be an rvalue reference -- the technique is known as perfect forwarding or universal references).  In the case given, `A&&` is `std::string const& &&` which resolves to `std::string const&`.  The problem lies elsewhere, when the OP did a `std::move` on a universal reference...